# Measuring average execution time in service

Tags: .net, windows, performancecounter

I'm trying to use Windows Performance Counters to measure the Hits Per Second and Seconds Per Hit of a WCF service and am seeing some strange results.

Currently, what I'm doing is this:

```
public void MethodToTime()
{
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.Start();

    //...do stuff...

    totalHitsCounter.Increment();  //this one works fine - NumberOfItems32 counter
    hitsPerSecondCounter.Increment();  //appears broken - RateOfCountsPerSecond32 counter
    secondsPerHitBaseTime.Increment(); //can't tell - AverageBase counter

    sw.Stop();
    secondsPerHitCounter.IncrementBy( sw.ElapsedTime );  //appears broken - AverageTimer32
}
```

At the end of the day, I want to know:

-This method was hit x times (in its lifetime).
-This method takes, on average, x.x seconds to execute.
-This method is called x times per second (across all service instances, since one call to the service results in one call to the method).

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to approach this issue?
Any feedback is much appreciated :)

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the seconds / hit is simply the inverse of the hits / second. You just need to divide 1 by your hits / second to get it.